# Python histogram of Randomized Quicksort Comparisons per Run

Tags: python, random, quicksort

I have to implement the Las Vegas Randomized Quicksort algorithm and count the number of comparisons for each run to sort a random list of integers and create a histogram for the obtained valus with the number of runs being 10^4.

I am having trouble with the histogram, as it shows somethig this:

[image]

Instead of a distribution similar to this:

[image]

Here is the code I imagined. The number of comparisons is correct.

```
import random
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def _inPlaceQuickSort(A, start, end):
    count = 0
    if start < end:
        pivot = randint(start, end)
        temp = A[end]
        A[end] = A[pivot]
        A[pivot] = temp

        p, count = _inPlacePartition(A, start, end)
        count += _inPlaceQuickSort(A, start, p - 1)
        count += _inPlaceQuickSort(A, p + 1, end)
    return count


def _inPlacePartition(A, start, end):

    count = 0
    pivot = randint(start, end)
    temp = A[end]
    A[end] = A[pivot]
    A[pivot] = temp
    newPivotIndex = start - 1
    for index in range(start, end):

        count += 1
        if A[index] < A[end]:  # check if current val is less than pivot value
            newPivotIndex = newPivotIndex + 1
            temp = A[newPivotIndex]
            A[newPivotIndex] = A[index]
            A[index] = temp

    temp = A[newPivotIndex + 1]
    A[newPivotIndex + 1] = A[end]
    A[end] = temp
    return newPivotIndex + 1, count 

if __name__ == "__main__": 
    comp = []
    for i in range(10):
        A={}
        for j in range(0, 10000):
            A[j] = random.randint(0, 10000)
        comp.append(_inPlaceQuickSort(A, 0, len(A) - 1)) 
    print(comp[i])

    plt.hist(comp, bins=50)
    plt.gca().set(title='|S|=10^4, Run=10^4', xlabel='Compares', ylabel='Frequency')
```

Comment: The code provided does not run.  If you've whittled it down to a test case to illustrate your question, that's great, but you need to test it before posting.

Comment: @pjs thank you for pointing that out, I had accidentally cut-out the comp list declaration. It runs now.

Comment: Not without prefixing `randint`s  to be `random.randint`.

Comment: Your problem seems to boil down to not generating enough samples.  Each spike in your first histogram is a single sample.  Generate a bunch more.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the program works as intended, it was just run with too small a sample size.

Comment: @pjs alright and thank you. I hope I didn't waste anyone's time with my question - never used Python before and didn't think the problem was so trivial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out by @Tom De Coninck and @pjs your problem is the sample size and, as you mentioned in a comment, if you increase your sample size it'll take a lot of time to generate it.

My idea would be to generate the data with a C++ software (much faster) and then plotting it with Python. With that I can generate and plot 10000 runs in less than 20 seconds.

Here it's my code (the quicksort algorithm was adapted from [C++ Program for QuickSort - GeeksforGeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/cpp-program-for-quicksort/))

The C++ code generate `out.txt` containing the total number of comparisons for each run separated by a newline. The Python script read the lines and plot them (with various bucket sizes, as the assignment states)

C++ Generator

```cpp
// g++ ./LVQuickSort.cpp -o lvquicksort

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>

int ARRAY_TO_SORT_SIZE = 10000;
int RUNS = 10000;

void swap(int *a, int *b)
{
  int t = *a;
  *a = *b;
  *b = t;
}

int partition(int arr[], int low, int high, int &comps)
{
  int pivot = arr[(rand() % (high - low)) + low];
  int i = low - 1;

  for (int j = low; j <= high - 1; j++)
  {
    comps++;
    if (arr[j] <= pivot)
    {
      i++;
      swap(&arr[i], &arr[j]);
    }
  }
  swap(&arr[i + 1], &arr[high]);
  return i + 1;
}

void quickSort(int arr[], int low, int high, int &comps)
{
  if (low < high)
  {
    int pi = partition(arr, low, high, comps);

    quickSort(arr, low, pi - 1, comps);
    quickSort(arr, pi + 1, high, comps);
  }
}

std::ofstream file;

void write_comps_to_file(int comps)
{
  file << comps << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
  file.open("./out.txt", std::fstream::trunc);

  for (size_t i = 0; i < RUNS; i++)
  {
    int *arr = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * ARRAY_TO_SORT_SIZE);
    for (int i = 0; i < ARRAY_TO_SORT_SIZE; i++)
      arr[i] = rand() % 1000;

    int comps = 0;

    if (i % (RUNS / 50) == 0)
      std::cout << i << "/" << RUNS<< std::endl;

    quickSort(arr, 0, ARRAY_TO_SORT_SIZE - 1, comps);
    write_comps_to_file(comps);
  }

  file.close();
}
```

Python plotter

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

f = open('out.txt', 'r')

binCounts = [10, 50, 100, 200, 1000, 5000]

for binCount in binCounts:
  vals = []
  f.seek(0)
  for line in f.readlines():
    vals.append(int(line))

  plt.hist(vals, bins=binCount)
  plt.gca().set(title='|S|=10^4 | Runs=10^4', xlabel='Comparisons', ylabel='Runs')
  plt.savefig(f'out{binCount}.png')
  plt.close()
```

Comment: Great solution, Giotino! :)

Answer (score 1):

You add 10 times something to your variable Comp, and your output shows a graph with 10 values in a histogram.

If you want something more to the distribution provided, you should increase the range in your I for loop to 1000 for example.

Comment: I see and thank you - the first loop would then represent the number or runs and the second the dimension of the list to sort. Is it normal than when working on Jupyter this is taking +20 mins? I still have not seen the histogram yet

Comment: @Anna It took me about a minute and a quarter to generate a histogram with 1000 samples, run from the command line.

Comment: Yeah the first loop is indeed your numbers of run, and the second represents your array size of what you want to sort. Running from the command line is indeed faster, and if you don't like that try PyCharm or something. I don't know a lot about the speed of Jupityr itself

Comment: Thank you both, I'm currently installing the needed packages.